# Terraform code to create a single tag with multiple values

Tags: azure, terraform

I am creating Azure resource groups using Terraform and I am struggling to make tagging requirements work.
Here is what I need my Terraform module to do
create a tag with key=Environment and
"allowedValues": = ["Test","Dev","PreProd","Prod"]

During the creation of the resource group, I want to input one of the values as a tag value. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to create resource group configurations for each environment, tagged with the appropriate environment name.

It might be worth looking into terraform.workspace (https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html)
After defining the workspaces in the command line, you can apply the terraform for the different environments separately while reusing much of the same code.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example"
  location = "West Europe"

  tags {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know which environment my resource group belongs to

Comment: You can reference the tag with azurerm_resource_group.example.tags["Environment"], although the value should be the same as terraform.workspace as that is effectively a global variable